# Copying a file from a windows machine to another windows machine through java

Tags: java, file, copy, pscp

I want to copy a file in local windows machine to another windows machine in the same LAN or Intranet using JAVA. I browsed and found that we can copy file using the `copy` command of ms-dos but it copies only to the shared folder of remote machine.

I don't want to copy to the shared folder but instead I want to copy to a folder inside C: drive which is not a shared one.

I tried using `pscp` command. It works for windows to linux file copying but not for windows to windows file copying.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to send the File with an selfwritten socket application.

Answer (score 0):

You cant copy a non shared folder. But u can write a server client application to send the data over the network:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html

Comment: Any FTP connection can be made? If so how?

Comment: U can use ftp connections in java, but than u would need a ftp server on the pc. Check out this:
http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/java-ftp.htm

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there are several ways to achieve it.

1. Provide two agents on the machine A and machine B, then you can copy the files to each machine by your own implement APIs.
2. Use the winrm protocol like chef does, more detail please refer to the below [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426(v=vs.85).aspx).

   You can also refer to some opensource project.

   ```
   https://github.com/cloudsoft/winrm4j

   https://github.com/OpenNMS/wsman
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot copy to a folder that it is not shared.

The operating system of the computer where you want to copy files will never allow you to write wherever you want for obvious security reasons.